# ViewPagerIndicator not updating position

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

When I am updating the viewpager and the viewpagerindicator object, the viewpager is updated and a new item is showing but the viewpagerindicator remains on its old position

```
featuredIndicators.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
this.featuredPager.setAdapter(new ProductImagePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), option.getAllImageUrl()));
featuredIndicators.setViewPager(this.featuredPager);
```

Please help

Comment: can u show more code

Comment: are you using any library for indicators?

Comment: Please look at the solution.. I tried it and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. 
Just add featuredIndicators.setCurrentItem(0);
before setting the adapter i.e., on the second line

Updated code :

```
featuredIndicators.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
featuredIndicators.setCurrentItem(0); 
this.featuredPager.setAdapter(new 
ProductImagePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),option.getAllImageUrl()));
featuredIndicators.setViewPager(this.featuredPager);
```